# Information about Deployment of android app in airwatch

Tags: android, airwatch

Can anyone guide me how to deploy my developed android app in airwatch ??

Is there any changes in the code to be carried out before we deploy?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, There is no need to change anything in your app. 
You can happily deploy the app to Airwatch from
Device  > Staging & Provisioning > Components > Application > Add Application

Answer (score 0):

Simply generate a signed APK and upload it to AirWatch. The signed APK can be generated via cordova CLI or [using Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).
If there are restrictions imposed by your AirWatch Admin you may need to whitelist your app by adding its package name in the whitelist.

Remember that anyone can unzip your APK and read the files inside, since it's not compiled. So be careful to remove any relevant data before publishing.